# Is there an academic counterpart to Grahams hierarchy of disagreement?

Tags: reference-request

Paul Graham's hierarchy of disagreement (http://paulgraham.com/disagree.html; https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/Graham%27s_Hierarchy_of_Disagreement-en.svg) is a quite well known model for classification of disagreeing responses, from name-calling to explicit refutation of the central argument of the adversary.

Is there any similar model described in an academic publication?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about academia. See the [help/on-topic].